# How do you subtract a value on one table with a value from another table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one called products and the other called orders.
Products as columns: id, plant_name, price, stock.
Orders as columns: id product_id, quantity.

When someone makes a order they pick a quantity. How do I reduce the quantity from the stock on the other table?

I am using controllers and elequent in Laravel if that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't you just update the `Products` table, ie `UPDATE Products SET stock = stock - :orderQty WHERE id = :orderProductId`? You could even do this in a trigger on inserts / updates to the `Orders` table

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a general implementation question?

It depends on how you process orders. If new ones are stored in a table and you're running a cron that goes through them, then loop the orders and update quantity one by one.

Ex:

```
 $newOrders = \DB::table('orders')->get();
 foreach ($newOrders as $order){
     $stock = \DB::table('products')->where('id', $order->product_id)->first()->stock;
     if($stock > $order->quantity){
         \DB::table('products')->where('id', $order->product_id)->decrement('stock',$order->quantity);
 }
```

If you process it on the fly in the controller, then skip the loop above and simply update the products table when you process the order..

Comment: i want to update the products table when i process the order but dont know how to do it . im a newbie